# The type or namespace name 'ProtoBuf' could not be found

Tags: c#, build, protobuf-net

I am fairly new to C# language so I just do not understand why my build produces error messages like the following.

```
The type or namespace name 'ProtoBuf' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What's interesting is that I don't get an error if I target '.NET framework 3.5' but I am getting an error once I set the project to target to '.NET framework 2.0'
Code stays the same and protobuf-net should be working with .NET 2.0 so I am not sure what I am missing.
FYI, the line that causes the error above is this line:

```
using ProtoBuf;
```

Can anyone give me some suggestion to resolve the error above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the protobuf-net assembly to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard download zip contains several dlls with cumulative features; in particular, the 3.0 version includes WCF hooks that only exist in 3.0 and above. While VS2008 is fairly forgiving here, VS2010 will usually point-blank refuse to include a reference for a higher framework.

If you don't need WCF, then the 2.0 version should work on any of 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 or 4.0 Otherwise - pick the right dll from the zip.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Marc. Your library really makes things easy for my work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to the *protobuf-net for .NET 2.0* assembly when you're targeting .NET 2.0, and a reference to the *protobuf-net for .NET 3.0* assembly when you're targeting .NET 3.0/3.5.